# Цвет рамки TextField

Tags: javafx

Если `TextField` находится в фокусе, то рамка вокруг него подсвечивается синим цветом.
Как переопределить цвет рамки на красный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прикручиваем `css` если не прикручен:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add( MyApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource( "/main.css" ).toExternalForm() );
//textField.getStyleClass( "myTextFieldClass" );
//textField.setId( "myTextFieldId" );
```

main.css:

```
/*
.myTextFieldClass:focused {
.#myTextFieldId:focused {
*/
.text-field:focused {
    -fx-border-color:red;
}
```